# WsTrust endpoint not found in metadata document

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless) to learn how to get token after user successful login.

Steps I have done so far:

1. I have registered myself(username and password) using this URL : https://MyCompany.b2clogin.com/MyCompany.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ApplicantSignInSignUp&client_id=some-client-id&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&response_mode=query
2. In the above example I have given AUTHORITY as "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyCompany.onmicrosoft.com/" or "https://MyCompany.b2clogin.com/tfp/MyCompany.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ApplicantSignInSignUp"
3. Client Id which I have received from the registration url in Step 1.

After running the code i see get the error for AUTHORITY as "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyCompany.onmicrosoft.com/":

```
    Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: WsTrust endpoint not found in metadata document
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:85)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.processPasswordGrant(AcquireTokenCallable.java:137)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:60)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call(AdalCallable.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

And get different error when I set AUTHORITY as "https://MyCompany.b2clogin.com/tfp/MyCompany.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ApplicantSignInSignUp"

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: Server returned HTTP response code: 404 for URL : https://mycompany.b2clogin.com/common/userrealm/sumantapakira@gmail.com?api-version=1.0, Error details : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The error occured while executing this part of the code:

```
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                "https://graph.microsoft.com", CLIENT_ID, username, password, null);
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, is it AUTHORITY URL is not correct or client id is not correct. I am using the same username/password which I had used during registration in Step #1

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you are using your global tenant admin account, which is your .onmicrosoft.com account. This error usually occurs if you are using the wrong credentials.

Your Client ID will match your application ID, as these are synonymous. So these need to be the same in your app registration and in your code. (This applies to your authority URL as well.)

Comment: Regrading global tenant account, when I registered myself in step#1, then I used my personal email id (something@gmail.com)and later when I login again using the same url then I get access token in browser call. But when I try this same username and password in the code then error occurs.  Can this username and password be used in the code or it should be different? I just want to get the access token once someone enter their user name and password.

Comment: If the authentication can only be used for the global tenant admin account, that essentially renders it completely useless as an authentication method for other users, surely? Either that or it opens a huge security hole by having to have each user authenticated as the admin user. Am I missing something here?