# msal4j - WsTrust endpoint not found in metadata document

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using `msal4j` library (1.9.1 version) to perform authentication, using OUTH2.0 and OpenId with Azure Active Directory, in the end I need to acquire token.
I was requested to do this operation through a proxy, so i tried to use code I found in msal4j documentation:

```
           Proxy proxy = new Proxy( Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        proxyUser,
                        proxyPassword.toCharArray() ) ;
            }
        });
        Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton("User.Read");
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build();
        PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId)
                .httpClient(new MyHttpClient(proxy,sslContext.getSocketFactory(), 0, 0))
                .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations").build();
        UserNamePasswordParameters paramaters = UserNamePasswordParameters
                .builder(scope, user, password.toCharArray()).build();
        //here I get the error
        IAuthenticationResult result = pca.acquireToken(paramaters).join();
```

but I am getting this error on acquireToken method

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: WsTrust endpoint not
> found in metadata document    at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
> Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: WsTrust
> endpoint not found in metadata document

I also tried `get` method instead of `join`, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

On Workaround on this Error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: WsTrust endpoint not
> found in metadata document

Using a **global tenant administrator account**, which is your **.onmicrosoft.com** account.

Please verify and make sure you have logged in with the proper account for the App you registered. This error usually occurs if you are using the wrong credentials.

**`username = xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com`**

**Note:** integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) supports federated users only - users created in Active Directory and backed by Azure AD. Users created directly in Azure AD without Active Directory backing (managed users) can't use this authentication flow.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#constraints-2)

For more details refer this SO Thread: [WsTrust endpoint not found in metadata document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793786/wstrust-endpoint-not-found-in-metadata-document)

Comment: which flow users created directly in Azure AD they should use?

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more what you asking?